# Unexpected calling of form destroy

Tags: delphi

I have a service running on a customer and specifically that I've noticed a strange behavior. Always before closing the service, closing routines (OnStop) are executed, after that enter in FormDestroy. However, in this customer, service is terminated unexpectedly (I know this because FormDestroy have been calling), but without entering into the routines of service shutdown.

Looking at the stack, everything seems normal:

```
01388f14 ****.exe Main****.      32766 TF****.FormDestroy
00506cbd ****.exe Forms                TCustomForm.DoDestroy
00506b23 ****.exe Forms                TCustomForm.BeforeDestruction
00404c95 ****.exe System               @BeforeDestruction
007a6a02 ****.exe dxRibbonForm     445 TdxCustomRibbonForm.Destroy
00487eaa ****.exe Classes              TComponent.DestroyComponents
00504a33 ****.exe Forms                DoneApplication
0045da9d ****.exe SysUtils             DoExitProc
00405683 ****.exe System               @Halt0
01435465 ****.exe Main****         289 initialization
75773388 kernel32.dll                  BaseThreadInitThunk
```

I could see this message in the Windows Event Viewer:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source *** cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Extended handler is registered

Could you give me a hint to find out what might be happening?

Comment: Let's start with your code. Can you share details how your service stops? Without it, I doubt anyone other than yourself will be able to guess what the issue is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Services can have GUIs...  Maybe it's not "advisable" for them to have them, but to say they're "not allowed" is wrong and doesn't help here.

Comment: @Ian No. Services cannot have GUIs. They run in session zero which is not interactive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I maintain a service with a GUI.  It works well on XP.  In Windows 7 it's a bit more of a pain as you have to use the Interactive Desktop service to access it - but they can have them.

Comment: @Ian That's not true. Since Vista, services run in session 0. The *allow service to interact with desktop* option merely allows the service to interact with a desktop in session 0 that the interactive user cannot see. You should not be using that option, even in XP, because of the security risks. You should have a separate desktop app that communicates with the service using IPC. This entire issue is comprehensively documented on MSDN. Attempting to create GUI objects in session 0 usually leads to errors and the stack trace in the question makes me think that is happening to the asker.

Comment: @Ian Interactive services are disabled starting at Vista and XP is not supported anymore so you can say no GUI allowed in services.

Comment: @David, mg30rg, have you read [`this topic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx) (especially the part about interactive service) ?

Comment: @TLama It's easy to be confused by that topic. Read right down to the bottom. The part that says, *All services run in Terminal Services session 0. Therefore, if an interactive service displays a user interface, it is visible only to the user who connected to session 0.* Also relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest

Comment: @David, you cannot (officially) switch to session 0 *desktop* (and interact there with a service UI). But it's not impossible ;-) Of course it is a wrong way.

Comment: @TLama Yes. I keep saying this but Ian and you argue against me.

Comment: @David, the rights and wrongs of what is being done aside, you yourself say that attempting to **create** UI objects will fail, but in the OP's case the issue is not *creating* UI objects but the *shutdown* process after an otherwise normal/uneventful/successful startup and subsequent session.  I think it is wrong to leap to a conclusion that the desktop interactivity or otherwise of the service/session is responsible.  It *might* still be, but it is by no means self evidently the case based on the information provided, imho.

Comment: @Deltics "Attempting to create GUI objects in session 0 usually leads to errors and the stack trace in the question makes me think that is happening to the asker." I'm not claiming that this is the cause of the problem for sure. Hence my only commenting. As for creating vs shutdown, it's easy to imagine that a failure to create could lead to an error on shutdown if the shutdown code assumed that creation succeeded and was not robust. Errors in Delphi shutdown are often not handled well. That service processes cannot show UI is not really up for debate.

Comment: All I'm saying is the OP makes no mention of start-up problems or issues whilst the service is running, which you might expect to arise from errors when creating UI objects during start-up, particularly if - as you say - it has not been robustly implemented.  imho more information is required to at least confirm an interactive session issue, rather than simply jumping to a conclusion which you appear to assert quite robustly, even if that were not your intention.  It's easy to imagine that a start-up error would lead to shutdown errors.  But then it's easy to imagine *anything*.  ;)

Comment: @Deltics I assert robustly that there should be no UI code in session 0. Clearly there is. The stack trace could not be any clearer. Is this the cause of the problem? No idea. Is it wrong to include GUI code in services? Yes.

Comment: This is what we are doing. The service is running with interface in session 0, and when we have to change any configuration in the service we just change the user session with another application that shows the session 0 to the user.

Comment: I have found in the delphi vcl source code a handler that halt the application when it receives a message WM_ENDSESSION (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889(v=vs.85) .aspx). If does my application is handling this message for some reason? Does this message is sent to the session 0 on a logoff of any user?

Comment: This is odd. Are you attempting to display UI from your service process?

Comment: Yes. This is a legacy system and there is not enough manpower to do it the right way. it works well on various customers, but apparently in only one it present the reported problem.

Answer (score 0):

The message in the **Event Viewer** is meaningless.  That is simply the standard error text for an event where the application which is the source of the event has not provided a DLL containing appropriate error messages to describe particular events.

Since your service appears to attempt to run interactively (with a UI), you presumably have set the **Interactive** property of your service to **TRUE**.  This means that your service starts with the **SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS** flag set.  Services started with this flag are liable to be prevented from running by the system, based on a system setting, [as described in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx).

In summary, in the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows** key of the registry, if the **NoInteractiveServices** value is set to **1** (zero), then such services are prevented from running.  In the case of a Delphi implemented service this means that the service process is started but will be terminated when it attempts to register the service itself, which may then cause problems in your UI destruction code if it contains assumptions that the initialisation of your service UI was successful.

On your affected customers system, change this registry value to a **0** (zero) to *allow* interactive services.  If your service is then able to start then this confirms that this is the source of your problem.

However, your customer may have specifically chosen to disallow such services for valid reasons (see the notes in that article for starters).

If that is the case and this is indeed the cause of your problem, them you will be forced to find an alternative approach to the UI needs of your service/application.  In the meantime, if the use of your service is important to that customer then this may provide a temporary solution if they are prepared to enable this setting on affected systems for a limited time while you make necessary changes to your application architecture.

Comment: Interesting answer, considering.